# Cannot move cursor up and down in text area (Firefox 77.0.1 (64-bit), Windows)

Tags: firefox, textarea

In my web app I cannot move the cursor up or down when editing a multi-row text in a simple text area. 
The cursor seems to be "locked" to either the first row or the last row. It can be moved left or right normally but not across line breaks.
It is impossible to place the cursor into one of the middle rows. Not by keyboard, and not by mouse either.

The same text area works like a charm in Chrome. I can place the cursor wherever I want and how I want - as expected.

Any idea why this is so and what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The text area's css property "user-select" was set to "none". Setting it to "auto" fixed the issue.